# Can I reset my TF2 statistics?

Tags: team-fortress-2

My "friend" (AKA me) wanted to have some fun, so he went onto an achievement idle server and murdered everyone several times. As a result of that, my "friend"'s statistics now show that he has earned 596 points as Medic (in one round too), which is impossible compared to the time that that friend has been playing Team Fortress 2. How can that person reset his statistics so that they do not frustrate him?

Comment: I was even lazier, I played as medic on a sniper vs sniper map and just hid behind the wall healing the sniper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can reset your Team Fortress 2 statistics by opening your Character Loadout, then navigate to the stats tab and click the reset stats button.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8CqblN7.png]

Comment: Would you happen to know if this resets your time as well?

Comment: @aman207 It does indeed

Answer (score -2):

you could also open the console & type in resetplayerstats.

Comment: This no longer works; they'll revert in a few hours.